# Hide category heading attribute if it's empty in Magento

Tags: php, magento

can someone please help me with the following? We display a list of categories the product belongs to in the following code (the category attribute we use is "creareseo_heading"). However, sometimes "creareseo_heading" attribute is empty but the row still appears with a label but no value. I believe we need some sort of an "if" statement to hide the row completely. I tried everything and couldn't make it work. Basically, I need the row to disappear completely if the list of  "creareseo_heading" category attributes is empty.

SOLVED!!! See below :)

```
<?php
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
    $_product = $this->getProduct();
    $currentCatIds = $_product->getCategoryIds();
    $catCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', $currentCatIds)
    ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
    ->setOrder('creareseo_heading', 'asc')
    ->addIsActiveFilter();
?>
<?php if($_additional = $this->getAdditionalData()): ?>
    <h2><?php echo $this->__('Additional Information') ?></h2>
    <table class="data-table" id="product-attribute-specs-table">
        <col width="25%" />
        <col />
        <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
        <?php $_attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_data['code']);
        if (!is_null($_product->getData($_attribute->getAttributeCode())) && ((string)$_attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) != '')) { ?>
            <tr>
                <th class="label"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
                <td class="data"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php
            $applicationGuides = array();
            foreach($catCollection as $cat){
                $c = $cat->getCreareseoHeading();
                if (!empty($c)) $applicationGuides[] = $c;
            }
        ?>
        <?php if(!empty($applicationGuides)): ?>
            <tr>
                <th class="label"><?php echo $this->__('Application Guide') ?></th>
                <td class="data">
                    <ul>
                    <?php foreach($applicationGuides as $cat): ?>
                        <li><?php echo $cat; ?></li>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </ul>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php endif;?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <script type="text/javascript">decorateTable('product-attribute-specs-table')</script>
<?php endif;?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        <?php
            /* Build list with no empty values */
            $applicationGuides = array();
            foreach($catCollection as $cat){
                $c = $cat->getCreareseoHeading();
                if (!empty($c)) $applicationGuides[] = $c;
            }
        ?>
        <?php if(!empty($applicationGuides)): ?>
        <tr>
            <th class="label"><?php echo $this->__('Application Guide') ?></th>
            <td class="data">
                <ul>
                <?php foreach($applicationGuides as $cat): ?>
                    <li><?php echo $cat; ?></li>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php endif;?>
```

Comment: what is the correct way to wrap the entire <tr> with an if statement? I basically don't want anything to appear if the cat attribute is empty. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Updated my answer for you. Also, if the table won't have anything else then you might as well put the `<tbody>` tags within the `if` statement as well.

Comment: just tried it but the bottom portion of the product page stopped rendering completely after i included the if statement. any ideas?

Comment: Can you show the HTML markup for **without* the `if` statement for the table?

Comment: I edited the original post to include the full code with other attributes in the table. those disappear properly if the attribute value is empty.

Comment: So you want to hide the whole table row for APPLICATION GUIDE if the list on the right is empty?

Comment: I've just updated the answer. Even though the list may not be empty, there are occassionally empty list items so this code will clean those empty ones out as well. It will only do the row if the list is not completely empty.

Comment: I just tried it and it breaks the page again for some reason. I can't see any attributes and there is no vertical scroll-bar. something is breaking the code.

Comment: I've checked over my code and can't see why it would cause a problem. Are you testing this directly on the site links you gave earlier? Double check that there is no problem before modifiying your code to replace with mine. If all is fine, then make sure you are only replacing the last `<tr>` of your code above.

Comment: Yes, I triple checked. definitely something is breaking the table because it does not render. i am testing it on a dev server. not public facing

Comment: Updated original answer with the new code. Somehow, checking for an empty result by calling directly `$cat->getCreareseoHeading()` was causing a problem.

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot, Trung! Can I maybe keep your email on file in case I need something?

Comment: Code looks good. I've added my linkedin to my profile so you can hit me up on there :)

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment so adding another answer to fit it to help you with debugging the problem...

Are any errors being reported? If you understand the code, maybe you can make gradual changes to the code and see if you are getting expected results. If you're not, then I suggest starting off with adding this code block to your original code, just above the `<tr>` block we are talking about...

```
        <?php
            /* Build list with no empty values */
            $applicationGuides = array();
            foreach($catCollection as $cat){
                $c = $cat->getCreareseoHeading();
                if (!empty($c)) $applicationGuides[] = $c;
            }
            var_dump($applicationGuides);
        ?>
```

Comment: no errors. I just added this block to the original code and same thing. the page just stops rendering html right before the attribute table starts. Thanks for all you help, by the way.

Comment: it doesn't break anymore but spits out the following string right above the whole table:

array(2) { [0]=> NULL [1]=> NULL }

Comment: the HTML breaks again right before the table starts same as before.

Comment: I think it works! I posted the final code above. Can you please check for errors and see if it's clean?